# How to add drop shadow to a picture via CLI?

Tags: inkscape, automation, drop-shadow, linux

I have a **bunch of pictures** (mostly screenshots, but it doesn't matter) to which I'd like **to add a drop shadow**. (Reason for it is to add a nice border, as they have white background and I use them on a white background.)

My current workflow is:

- open the `.png` file in Inkscape,
- `Filters/Shadow and glow/Drop shadow`,
- select a `3px` blur radius, with a `2px 2px` offset,
- export the modified `.png`.

However, this is done all manually… and it is quite annoying when I have more than… 2 pictures.

I know Inkscape can be used with Command Line Interface (CLI) (I'm on Ubuntu 18.04). I know how to import and export files. However, I don't know how to apply a given filter.

Here's what I've tried, it didn't work:

```
$ inkscape --verb org.inkscape.effect.filter.ColorDropShadow --verb FileSave --verb FileClose image.png
```

Hence, could you tell me **how to add drop shadow to a picture using CLI?**
(This could be done using either Inkscape, or any other open-source software running on Linux)

Comment: My current progress so far: `$ inkscape --verb org.inkscape.effect.filter.ColorDropShadow --verb FileSave --verb FileClose image.png` but it is not working.

Comment: You might get more out of your your cmd if you used imagamagick instead

Comment: You need to export to png, not save.

Comment: For this verb a GUI is required as the text output says: `WARNING: ignoring verb org.inkscape.effect.filter.ColorDropShadow - GUI required for this verb.`

Comment: ... and also, you need to select an object before you can apply a filter to it.

Comment: The comments about the GUI are ... not correct. It requires a GUI, but with the .noprefs version of the verb, it does not need user input. So yes, Inkscape will open, but the script will still be running.

Comment: So, to do this properly your script needs to: open the file, select everything in it, apply the noprefs dropshadow filter, then export the selected object to png as a whole (the filter will make it larger, so exporting the page area will not work).

Comment: @Moini Thank you! I'll try with your comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than using the vector graphic tool Inkscape I would recommend the ultimate command line tool for bitmap manipulations: [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php).

It should be available through your distribution repositories. This tool comes with many effects, including generating a drop shadow.

This is basically done with the [`convert -shadow`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#shadow) option but you then need to combine the generated background image again with the original. This can all be done in a one-line command using `-layers merge` option:

```
convert input.jpg \( +clone -background black -shadow 50x10+15+15 \) +swap -background none -layers merge +repage shadow.png
```

Useful options for the drop shadow are determined with `-background <color>` and `-shadow percent-opacity{xsigma}{+-}x{+-}y{%}`. The example above generates a grey drop shadow with 50% opacity, 10% size and x=+15% 
y=+15% offset:

[image]

Source of above information and more options, and different shadow types see:

- Image Magick Manual: [Bluring and Sharpening](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/blur/#shadow)

Comment: this is exactly what I'm needing – enabling drop-shadow settings as CLI argument is a real plus. thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately this Q&A appears as the most trusted or relevant source when you search for how to add a drop shadow in Inkscape with the CLI. I agree that the question was about bitmap graphics, but I'm now a bit disappointed and confused. It's not getting better when asking "GPT", just more fluff with the same reference and remarks that it can be done, apparently.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Takkat](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/117404/83351)'s answer, here is the bash function I have added to my `.bashrc`:

```
function dropshadow () {
    filename=$(basename -- "$1")
    # extension="${filename##*.}"
    basename="${filename%.*}"
    # we want to enforce png (even if .jpg as input)
    suffix="_shadow.png"
    convert "$1" \( +clone -background black -shadow 50x10+5+5 \) +swap -background none -layers merge +repage "$basename$suffix"
}
```

- **Usage**: `dropshadow <yourfile.ext>`,
- **Output**: creates `<yourfile>_shadow.png` in your current working directory.